# How to convert List<Map<String,Long> to TreeMap or Map?

Tags: java, list, dictionary, merge

How to convert a List< Map.Entry < String,Long > > to TreeMap < String,Long > ?

```
    TreeMap<String,Long> tm1=new TreeMap<String, Long>();     
    List<Map.Entry<String,Long>> first = new ArrayList<Map.Entry<String,Long>>(tm1.entrySet());

    //Convert list back to TreeMap
    ??
```

I can't use Java 8 because this program run in a Hadoop program in Amazon Web Services that support only Java 1.7.

Comment: Traverse the List, store each element on the TreeMap. It's not hard to do.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Thre is not a method more efficient?

Comment: I don't think there's a more efficient way.  I couldn't find a built-in method to construct a map from a collection of `Map.Entry` objects.  And if there were, it would probably just iterate over the list and add everything anyway, so it really wouldn't be much more efficient.  (The only way I think things could be made more efficient is if you started with a `TreeSet<Map.Entry<String,Long>>`, which is not a list.  But for a general list, I can't think of an algorithm that would be more efficient.)

Comment: If you're using Java 7, use diamonds. You write the full generic type in the variable type, but in the initialisation of it, have the compiler infer it.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate over list and add to treemap. E.g.

```
    for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : first) {
        tm1.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
```